# Read multiple lines from textfile into array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, streamreader

I'm working on a small program which holds information about people. The information is stored in a textfile as a sentence and the words are separated by ";". I know how to read the lines with a streamreader, I do this upon clicking on a button.
I then split the sentence in words and save them in an array.
When clicking a second button I want the separate words displayed in different textboxes (their name, birth date, etc.). And every time you click the button the info of the next person is being displayed until the whole list is displayed.

The problem I encounter is that only the last value of my array is displayed in the textboxes. I understand that every time I loop over the readline(), the array is being filled with strings and overwritten. I don't want to use a list for now as I already found an answer with lists. I just can't find a way to save or so my information in the array and display it later on.

I'll put my code here:

```
string[] words = new string[10];

private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line = "";
    try
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader("pers.txt");

        while (file.Peek() != -1)
        {       
            line = file.ReadLine();   
            words = line.Split(';');              
        }
        file.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("File read", "Info");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found");
        return;
    }
}

private void btnOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Text = words[0];
    txtdate.Text = words[1];
    txtNr.Text = words[2];
    txtStreet.Text = words[3];
    txtPost.Text = words[4];
    txtCity.Text = words[5];

    MessageBox.Show("All persons showed", "Info");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to read lines one by one.

```
string[][] words = null;
private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string line = "", contents = "";
   try
   {
       using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("pers.txt"))
       {
          contents = file.ReadToEnd();
       }
       string[] lines = contents.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       words = new string[lines.GetLength(0)][];
       for (int i = 0; i < lines.GetLength(0); i++)
       {
          string[] split_words = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ';' });
          words[i] = new string[split_words.GetLength(0)];
          for (int j = 0; j < split_words.GetLength(0); j++)
              words[i][j] = split_words[j];
        }
        MessageBox.Show("File read", "Info");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found");
       return;
   }
}
```

Declaring a jagged array `string[][] words = null;` will allow you to address each word on any specific line by indexes. E.g. `string name = words[0][0]` to get a value from the 1st line and you know that some name is located in the 1st column.

So, for the button:

```
int current_index = -1;
private void btnOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    current_index = words.GetLength(0) == current_index - 1 ? 0 : ++current_index;

    txtName.Text = words[current_index][0];
    txtdate.Text = words[current_index][1];
    txtNr.Text = words[current_index][2];
    txtStreet.Text = words[current_index][3];
    txtPost.Text = words[current_index][4];
    txtCity.Text = words[current_index][5];

    MessageBox.Show("All persons showed", "Info");
}
```

Also, use `using` when reading/writing files, it is really convenient!

Comment: I'd really advise you to use `.List()`, it is more convenient. I know of a situation when you cannot use List()s, namely when `using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap`, but you can use regular `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`. Well, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `File.ReadLines` that lets you enumerate the lines without reading the entire file into an array. Keep an index of the current line and skip to that, and increase the index to get the next line the next time:

```
int index = 0;
string[] words;

private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    string line = File.ReadLines("pers.txt").Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
    if (line != null) {
      words = line.Split(';');
      index++;
    } else {
      // reached the end of the file
    }
    MessageBox.Show("File read", "Info");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found");
  }
}
```

Naturally reading through the file to get a specific line is not efficient, but that's what you have to do if you don't want to keep the lines in a list. (Files are not line based (or even character based), so there is no way to get a specific line without reading the previous lines.)